# How to display the monthpicker in diferent div using Jquery

Tags: jquery, monthcalendar

I need to display the monthpicker **UI** inside one different div but the selected value will fetch to the input field using Jquery. I am explaining my code below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Parent-Child Communication</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery-ui.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="monthpicker.css" />
        <script src="jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
        <script src="jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <script src="monthpicker.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input id="sDate" type="text" />
        <div id="packagetour_datepickerpick"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $('#sDate').Monthpicker();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here I need to display the monthpicker inside `<div id="packagetour_datepickerpick"></div>` but the selected value should fetched to the input field. (Here is the demo code
)[http://plnkr.co/edit/vtth4dTXTUapFfFQB8MC?p=preview].

Comment: Could you share jsfiddle link?

Comment: @NirajKaushal : sure.Let me to make plunkr demo.

Comment: @NirajKaushal: check this http://plnkr.co/edit/vtth4dTXTUapFfFQB8MC?p=preview link.

Comment: Which version of `monthpicker` your are using?

Comment: It looks like the version is a bit old. In recent version there is a possibility to do inline rendering: https://github.com/KidSysco/jquery-ui-month-picker/wiki/Inline-Menu

Comment: @NirajKaushal : Dont know regarding the version but I download it from `https://www.jqueryscript.net/time-clock/Minimal-jQuery-Month-Picker-Plugin-Simple-MonthPicker.html` site.

Comment: @extempl, Yes, I have created a working sample for subhra but was confused about version.

Comment: @NirajKaushal : Your plunkr is same as me.

Comment: @subhra I have created on jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/nirajkaushal/knr1htvd/

Comment: @NirajKaushal : Yes, in your code its working. same I did but its showing `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).MonthPicker is not a function`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Note: As discussed on comment section**

---

I have created a running example which use following libraries.

1. https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js
2. https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js
3. https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.min.css
4. https://rawgit.com/KidSysco/jquery-ui-month-picker/v3.0.0/demo/MonthPicker.min.css
5. https://rawgit.com/KidSysco/jquery-ui-month-picker/v3.0.0/demo/MonthPicker.min.js

```js
$("#packagetour_datepickerpick").MonthPicker({
    SelectedMonth: '04/' + new Date().getFullYear(),
    AltField: '#sDate',
    OnAfterChooseMonth: function(selectedDate) {
        // Do something with selected JavaScript date.
        // console.log(selectedDate);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://rawgit.com/KidSysco/jquery-ui-month-picker/v3.0.0/demo/MonthPicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/KidSysco/jquery-ui-month-picker/v3.0.0/demo/MonthPicker.min.js"></script>


<input id="sDate" type="text" />
<div id="packagetour_datepickerpick"></div>
```

I hope it will help you. :)

Comment: but its little bit incompatible with `ui/1.12.1`.

Comment: May be but its compatible with ui-1.11.4

Comment: Its also working with latest version of jQuery UI `1.12.1`. I have updated my answer check it out

Comment: bus after adding `SelectedMonth: new Date().getMonth()+'/' + new Date().getFullYear()` to get current month, the year is changing.

Comment: ohh..month starts from 0 thats why..any way thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Its my pleasure... :)